# Filetype conversion using apache camel from csv to xml

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to convert a csv file into xml file using apache camel i am facing problem in mar shalling and unmarshalling ....The code of this program is ......

```
package com.mycompany.camel.java;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.CsvRecord;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.DataField;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", skipFirstLine = true)

public class EmployeeDTO implements Serializable{
@XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 1)
      private int employeeId;
      @XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 2)
      private String firstName;
      @XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 3)
      private String lastName;
      @XmlAttribute
      @DataField(pos = 4)
      private String role;
}


package com.mycompany.camel.java;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;

public class ConvertorRoute implements RoutesBuilder{

@Override
public void addRoutesToCamelContext(CamelContext context) throws Exception {
  context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
public void configure() {
  try {
            DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat("com.mycompany.camel.java");
                  from("file://C:/Users/rahul/Desktop/Employee.csv").
                  unmarshal(bindy).
                  marshal().
                  xstream().
                  to("file://C:/Users/rahul/Desktop/employee.xml");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     });
}


public static void main(String[] args) { 
     try{
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
          ConvertorRoute route = new ConvertorRoute();
          route.addRoutesToCamelContext(context);
          context.start();
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          context.stop();
      }catch(Exception exe){
          exe.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

**Error i am facing is:**

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XStreamDataFormat@1aa9f99] <<< in route: Route[[From[file://C:/Users/JaHnAvI/Desktop?fileName=Employe... because of Data format 'xstream' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:879)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:172)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:722)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1789)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1575)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)
at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)
at com.mycompany.camel.java.ConvertorRoute.main(ConvertorRoute.java:36)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'xstream' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:89)
at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:79)
at org.apache.camel.model.MarshalDefinition.createProcessor(MarshalDefinition.java:150)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:461)
at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:179)
at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:876)
... 8 more


org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XStreamDataFormat@1aa9f99] <<< in route: Route[[From[file://C:/Users/JaHnAvI/Desktop?fileName=Employe... because of Data format 'xstream' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:879)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:172)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:722)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1789)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1575)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1444)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1412)
    at com.mycompany.camel.java.ConvertorRoute.main(ConvertorRoute.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'xstream' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.model.DataFormatDefinition.getDataFormat(DataFormatDefinition.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.model.MarshalDefinition.createProcessor(MarshalDefinition.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:461)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:179)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:876)
    ... 8 more
```

Please help me in fixing this error.....

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Thanks Namphibian for your solution...but still i am facing the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

1. I tested same example in my local machine with the following dependencies.
2. file paths are not correct if you are running it in windows.

check the code below.
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CamelBasic</groupId>
  <artifactId>CamelBasic</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <properties>
        <camel-version>2.12.0</camel-version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
       <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
       <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
       <artifactId>camel-csv</artifactId>
       <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
       <artifactId>camel-xstream</artifactId>
       <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-bindy</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-version}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

path example:
file:D:\CamelTestData\csvDir?fileName=input.csv

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the dependency for Xstream in your maven file? If you are using maven please add the following to your project file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-xstream</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

The error clearly states you are missing a component

Comment: i added dependency suggested by you...but i am still facing the same problem...do you have any program to convert csv file to xml using apache camel pls post...Thank you...

Comment: @Rahulbujji can you post the error log after adding the Maven dependency

Comment: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XStreamDataFormat@55e55f] <<< in route: Route[[From[file://C:/Users/rahul/Desktop/Employee.csv]] -... because of Data format 'xstream' could not be created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel component is present on the classpath....This is main error i am facing in this...